# Как получить объект нужного типа?

Tags: c#, winforms

У меня есть список с формами(System.Windows.Forms.Form).
Я хочу из этого списка получить форму конкретного типа.
Наверное по коду будет понятнее:

```
public List<Form> Forms = new List<Form>()
{
    new HelloForm(),
    new SomeForm()
};

public T GetForm<T>() where T : Form
{
    return Forms.Find(x => x.GetType() == T);
}
```

В функции GetForm ошибка: T является тип, который не допустим в данном контексте. 
Как это написать правильно?

Уточнение: .Net Framework 2.0 (Linq отсутствует)

Comment: Можно попробовать вместо обобщенного метода - передавать параметр с типом, но как-то не очень красиво.

Comment: `return Forms.OfType<T>().FirstOrDefault();` ?

Comment: Видимо мне стоило уточнить, что это Framework 2.0. Линка нету. Его можно подключить отдельно? (неа, ему нужен 4.5)

Comment: ну сделайте без Linq, это ж просто цикл - `foreach(var f in Forms) if (f.GetType() == typeof(T)) return (T)f; return default(T);`

Comment: Блин, ну я же вроде пробовал так) Спасибо, @tym32167! Выручаете не в первый раз!
Оформляйте как ответ)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Все делается просто

```
public T GetForm<T>() where T : Form
{
    foreach(var f in Forms) if (f.GetType() == typeof(T)) return (T)f;
    return default(T);
}
```